# How to play sound for callee in asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk, fastagi

For dialing a number I am using

```
exec("DIAL", "DAHDI/g0/" + callingPhoneNo + "," + currentTimeOut + ",mg,");
```

in my java application.
And for playing sound for caller using this snippet:

```
exec("background", "custom/incorrectPassword");
```

But how can I play sound for call receiver after callee the phone up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in :[voip-info](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial) it is possible with A option.
Means that for this case using

```
exec("DIAL", "DAHDI/g0/" + callingPhoneNo + "," + currentTimeOut + ",mg|A(custom/greet)");
```

command, play `greet` file for callee after picking the phone up.

Comment: I have the same problem, tried your code but it does not work for me. It gives me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to send command from an invalid thread" but if that answer is marked it should work. I guess I can not use exec commands but i'm not sure. can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 options for doing this. Actually only one option needed, but historically we have 3

1) Exactly for this purpose, option A in Dial command diallout parameters

> ```
> A(x): 
>         x - The file to play to the called party
>     Play an announcement to the called party, where <x> is the prompt
>     to be played
> ```

2) Privacy mode options.

> p: This option enables screening mode. This is basically Privacy
>           mode without memory.

```
P([x]): Enable privacy mode. Use <x> as the family/key in the AstDB
    database if it is provided. The current extension is used if a database
    family/key is not specified.
```

Privacy play message based on callerid and ask name if not found

3) Macro and Gosub on answer. Just different and most flexible ways to do something with called, using that you can collect input/confirm/decline call etc.

> M(macro[^arg[^...]]):
>
> ```
>         macro - Name of the macro that should be executed.
>
>         arg - Macro arguments
>
>     Execute the specified <macro> for the *called* channel  before
>     connecting to the calling channel. Arguments can be specified to the Macro
>     using '^' as a delimiter. The macro can set the variable ${MACRO_RESULT}
>     to specify the following actions after the macro is finished executing:
>
>         ${MACRO_RESULT}: If set, this action will be taken after
>         the macro finished executing.
>
>             ABORT: Hangup both legs of the call
>
>             CONGESTION: Behave as if line congestion was
>             encountered
>
>             BUSY: Behave as if a busy signal was encountered
>
>             CONTINUE: Hangup the called party and allow the
>             calling party to continue dialplan execution at the next priority
>
>             GOTO:[[<context>^]<exten>^]<priority>: Transfer the
>             call to the specified destination.
>
>
>
>
> U(x[^arg[^...]]): 
>
>     x - Name of the subroutine to execute via Gosub
>     arg - Arguments for the Gosub routine
>
> Execute via Gosub the routine <x> for the *called* channel before
> connecting to the calling channel. Arguments can be specified to the Gosub
> using '^' as a delimiter. The Gosub routine can set the variable ${GO
> SUB_RESULT} to specify the following actions after the Gosub returns.
>
>     ${GOSUB_RESULT}: 
>         ABORT: Hangup both legs of the call.
>         CONGESTION: Behave as if line congestion was
>         encountered.
>         BUSY: Behave as if a busy signal was encountered.
>         CONTINUE: Hangup the called party and allow the
>         calling party to continue dialplan execution at the next priority.
>         GOTO:[[<context>^]<exten>^]<priority>: Transfer the
>         call to the specified destination.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use special extension(Macros) in Dial application. This is run after callee pick up phone. In which you can pass parameters too.

Example 2: Dial macro
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial